# render view in the class library project

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view in the `Views` folder and I have a class library project. In this project I want to render view to string.

```
public class DumpService
{
     public void Method()
     {
         var renderedView = SomeMethodForRenderingView();
     }
}
```

I have found some answers, but there are used controller context which I don't have in the class library project.
How can I do this?

Comment: Did you see this: http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/

Comment: @AliRızaAdıyahşi: I don't want to store view in the separated assembly

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the view text - just open it with and read the text, and then parse it with :

```
Razor.Parse
```